# 'list' object has no attribute 'resolve' Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on Python Django 1.5 on Vista. When I try to access localhost:8000/add/producto, I got the following error:

`AttributeError at /add/producto`

`list' object has no attribute 'resolve'`

Under `addProducto.html`, I have

```
<html>
    Agregando Producto
</html>
```

Under `views.py`, I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def add_product_view(request):
    return render_to_response('ventas/addProducto.html', 
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Under `urls.py` ,

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns,url

urlpatterns = patterns('','demo.apps.ventas.views', url(r'^add/producto/$', 
                    'add_product_view', name = "vista_agregar_producto")),
)
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: The error is not happening in the posted code.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please.

Comment: I don't see a list in there, but the first problem is that it's not even valid python (must be a bad copy and paste). 2nd, it's not the correct patterns syntax. You have duplicated view preixes. The first arg is the view prefix string. The 2nd+ is the tuple of url+view.

Answer (score -2):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns,url

+++urlpatterns = patterns('demo.apps.ventas.views', url(r'^add/producto/$', 
                    'add_product_view', name = "vista_agregar_producto")),
)



----urlpatterns = patterns('','demo.apps.ventas.views', url(r'^add/producto/$', 
                    'add_product_view', name = "vista_agregar_producto")),
)
```

Comment: It would really be better if you actually explained your answer instead of just dumping in code.